# Custom UIViewController add issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I Created a `UIViewController` that I want to add on the top of all of my views, the problem is that it's visible for only 1 sec and then disappears from the screen and deallocated. Why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
- (void)show
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    self.window.screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [mainWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.window addSubview:self.view];

    self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
    self.backgroundImage.image = [self takeSnapshot];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.alpha = 1.0f;

    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Screen deallocated.");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to display the view controllers view on the main window? unless this is the app delegate, you're going to want to present the view controller and that is what is going to handle and display the view. you also don't need a dealloc method (unless you're, like deregistering a observer or another one of a small handful of things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the graph of your objects,I assume self is some view controller.
your self.view is subview of Appdelegates UIWindow. When you do

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

your Appdelegate window gets released subsequently your view controller(self) will also be released.

So I would suggest you to retain UIWindow instance before actually releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

You must save variable for your UIViewController in that place from where "show" method was called. For example - just create property…

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomViewController *cvc;

Otherwise instance of your UIViewController will be released at the end of that method. Because your object won't have any strong references…

Answer (score 1):

If you work with XIB, you can use this code: You have to create an UIView class, for example HeaderView. In your UIViewController [ I will call it BaseViewController] .h you have to add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) HeaderView *headerView;
```

and in .m you have to add this code:

```
- (id)init {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    [self configureMenuView:self];
}

return self;
```

}

```
- (void)configureMenuView:(UIViewController *)vc {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
    for( id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[HeaderView class]]) {
            self.headerView = (BannerView *)currentObject;
            self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
            self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [vc.view addSubview:self.headerView];
            break;
        }
    }
     [self.bannerView.closeHeaderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeHeaderrView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // it's only an example if you want add some button in your header.
```

So, in every view controller you have to import this class: BaseViewContoller and to add it like parent:

```
@interface TestViewController : HeaderViewController
```

Hope it works for you :)